# I get an Error 6 with Asciimatics and Python

Tags: python-2.7, ascii

I am learning how to use asciimatics with Python.
When I try to run the following code:

```
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from time import sleep

def demo(screen):
    screen.print_at('Hello world!', 0, 0)
    screen.refresh()
    sleep(10)

Screen.wrapper(demo)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\Westhope\2.0\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    Screen.wrapper(demo)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asciimatics\screen.py", line 1336, in wrapper
    unicode_aware=unicode_aware)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asciimatics\screen.py", line 1245, in open
None))
error: (6, 'CreateFile', 'The handle is invalid.')
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you are not running in a proper console/terminal window and you need to run inside the standard Windows command prompt instead.

See https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#i-can-t-run-it-inside-pycharm-or-other-ides for more details.